# Only white screen appears when my Sencha application is launched in OnePlus 5 with Oreo

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-webview, sencha-touch

I have a sencha touch app made for cross platform and its working fine with any device but when I tested with One Plus 5 with Oreo version then it is showing just a blank white screen on launching... nothing else. Does anyone have any idea whats happening here. In the logs I am getting the following

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.hb>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/SafeBrowsingResponse;
03-12 15:17:55.922 1192-1192/sg.gov.acra.ACRAOnTheGo I/zygote64:     
at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean(WebViewChromium.java:42)
```

I think we are using cordova plugins to support web view. Also oreo emulator is working good for the app. I need to know what is the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
mobile chrome
```

in supported browsers along with other browser names in

```
android > assets > app.js
```

and then the build that was created was working fine on oreo 8. This is currently a temporary solution as I have to add this line again when I build using sencha but it is right now working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was just going through my project and found that I am using cordova version 4.3 and latest cordova is 6 something. Main thing is currently cordova is not giving support to Android 8.0 Oreo or maybe full support is not there atleast not for my cordova version 4.3. Below is the link of cordova official website with the supported corresponding version to android.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/